# How do you isolate the scope of trailing text after a scope-match within vscode syntax grammars

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, textmate

Im attempting to write a syntax grammar but have ran into an issue when attempting to properly scope text after a block comment:

```
/*
block comment
*/ troublesome text
```

With the following 'pattern', `troublesome text` is scoped as `invalid.illegal.mircscript`, `comment.block.mircscript` when instead it should be scoped as just `invalid.illegal.mircscript`

```
{
    "name": "comment.block.mircscript",
    "begin": "^\\x20*/\\*",
    "end": "^\\x20*\\*/(\\x20*\\S.*$)?"
    "endCaptures": {
        "1": { "name": "invalid.illegal.mircscript" }
    }
}
```

But if I split the pattern, `troublesome text` doesn't get matched/scoped at all:

```
{
    "patterns": [
        {
            "name": "comment.block.mircscript",
            "begin": "^\\x20*/\\*",
            "end": "^\\x20*\\*/"
        },
        {
            "name": "invalid.illegal.mircscript",
            "match": "\\G(?<=\\*/)\\x20*\\S.*$"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I go about excluding the trailing text from the `comment.block.mircscript` while still matching directly after a block comment to scope it for `invalid.illegal.mircscript`?

Comment: I believe that grammars have an order, and the first match is what counts, would you try re-ordering your patterns so that `invalid.illegal.mircscript` is listed before `comment.block.mircscript`?

Answer (score 0):

The scoping is because your entire rule has `"name": "comment.block.mircscript"` so anything it matches (including begin/end) will have that scope.

To avoid this, you can omit the top level `name` and instead use `contentName` while explicitly setting scopes on the `begin` and `end` captures:

```
{
    "contentName": "comment.block.mircscript",
    "begin": "^\\x20*/\\*",
    "beginCaptures": {
        "0": "comment.block.mircscript.begin"
    },
    "end": "(^\\x20*\\*/)(\\x20*\\S.*$)?"
    "endCaptures": {
        "1": { "name": "comment.block.mircscript.end" },
        "2": { "name": "invalid.illegal.mircscript" }
    }
}
```

`contentName` only sets the scope of the content matched inside of a begin/end rule, while excluding the begin/end matches themselves

Comment: does this not create 3 different scope-blocks for the comment: the opening tag, the content, and the closing tag? Is there a way to properly scope it so the entire comment is a single block